# VNC - How to give permission on only certain part of screen?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote

I'm looking for VNC software that allows me to display the entire remotely accessed desktop but with one part in read-only mode and the other in write mode.

In essence, I need to access the supervision computer of an OT network, and I want the person who is remotely accessing the PC to only be able to use the lower part of the HMI view, which allows navigation through different pages.

Thank you

Comment: Software recommendations are offtopic here, go to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, but this is an XY problem